# iPhone delete messages like interface

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, imessage

I want to delete rows in a UITableView, I need to provide the delete button not by swipe but in a way similar to delete messages functionality in iPhones. In which on clicking edit a small red circle appears on the left in the cell which rotates when clicked and the delete button is shown. How to implement this?

Like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance you're going to show us some code you've written, so we can see where you're going wrong...?

Comment: You know the class you're dealing with, and [the documentation for that class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/) describes how the editing mode works.  **Please** check the documentation before you ask people for help.  If you check the documentation but get stuck, tell people which part of it you are stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Apple documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details on how to achieve this. In particular:

> When sent a `setEditing:animated`: message (with a first parameter of
>   `YES`), the table view enters into editing mode where it shows the
>   editing or reordering controls of each visible row, depending on the
>   `editingStyle` of each associated `UITableViewCell`. Clicking on the
>   insertion or deletion control causes the data source to receive a
>   `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath`: message. You commit
>   a deletion or insertion by calling
>   `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`: or
>   `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`:, as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

write this     `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;` in `viewDidLoad` method. After that implement this method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {



        [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];


    }
}
```